# replication of number by other column in r

Tags: r, replication, rep

How can I use replication function in the following situation:

```
mydata <- data.frame (var1 = 1:4, replication = c(3, 5, 3, 7))

mydata
  var1 replication
1    1           3
2    2           5
3    3           3
4    4           7
```

I want a result like this:

```
1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2,  3,3,3,  4,4,4,4,4,4,4
```

1 is repeated 3 times, 2 for 5 times and so on

I tried apply function, do not do any thing good.

```
apply (mydata,2,rep )
```

Comment: `apply` doesn't do the job because a vector of the values for each column is given to `rep` as the first argument, and no second argument is passed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were on the right track: `rep` is the function for the job. But try this instead:

```
with(mydata, rep(var1, replication))
```

The way you're using `apply` here, `rep` is being called on each of the columns individually. It would be like calling `rep(1:4)`, then `rep(c(3,5,3,7))`, and combining the results into a `matrix`.

<s>`apply` is a great function to be familiar with, but it isn't the tool for this job. In fact, a solution to this using `apply` would be pretty ugly:</s>

```
unlist(apply(mydata, 1, function(var1.rep) do.call(rep, unname(as.list(var1.rep)))))
```

@MatthewLundberg demonstrates the appropriate way to do this with `apply` in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I am trying similar approach for seq function but do not work (with(mydata, seq(var1, replication, 0.1)) but do not work, is there any important difference between rep and seq function ?

Comment: The vectorized solution is best, but the apply needn't be quite so ugly: `unlist(apply(mydata, 1, function(r) rep(r[1],r[2])))`.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg thanks, I probably use `do.call` way more often than I should...

Comment: In case anyone not familiar with the "with" command comes to this page, it is not needed.  This more simple (to me, at least) version will work:  **rep( mydata$var1, mydata$replication )**